# Accept-Datetime header field in HTTP

Tags: html, definition

I found on wikipedia that [Accept-Datetime header field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields#Request_fields)  is "Acceptable version in time".

It isn't really clear to me what is the meaning of that field and what does it really provide?

Comment: http://www.mementoweb.org/guide/rfc/#Accept-Memento-Datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Accept-Datetime` header is an HTTP header, not HTML. It is not a standard header according to [HTTP specifications](https://www.mnot.net/blog/2014/06/07/rfc2616_is_dead). You should consult the specific descriptions of this header in the applicable drafts or documentation, such as the informational [RFC 7089](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7089), which describes it as follows:

> The "Accept-Datetime" request header is transmitted by a user agent
> to indicate it wants to access a past state of an Original Resource.
> To that end, the "Accept-Datetime" header is conveyed in an HTTP
> request issued against a TimeGate for an Original Resource, and its
> value indicates the datetime of the desired past state of the
> Original Resource.